# Angular method understanding

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

example code below:

```
<div id=A>

 <div id=B>
  <input type="text" onkeyup="some.doSomething()">
 </div>

 <div id=C>
  <button id=btn onclick=some.next('A')>NEXT</button>
 </div>

</div>
```

```
public doSomething(): void {
//do something
}
public next(): void {
//go next
}
```

I don't understand the relation between some.next('A') and next() method.
The next method itself isn't taking any parameter, yet div id is included inside html call.

Comment: This will not work. From where did you take this code? - Put context when you ask question to help people understand and help you.

Comment: Need more explanation. Second code is the .ts for the html view? Show the component/class with the context. Why are you calling some.next? you should call next() in the html i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that Javascript code, you should call in your HTML the method doSomething() directly, the same for next() without params, otherwise won't work.